# Kinect camera apparently not working - What can I do?

Tags: kinect

We have had a Kinect for the past five months, and it used to work fine. Now, however, it doesn't look like it is "seeing" anything. It doesn't recognize any motion. The little box in the corner of the screen is solid black. Attempts to calibrate it fail. We have connected it to another Xbox, and got the same result.

Is there anything we should try before giving up and replacing it?

Comment: My standard answer was going to be 'have you tried calibrating', then 'have you tried another Xbox', with that out of the way, I think you've got to consider replacement. Good luck!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you tried recalibrating user the sensor calibration card?

Comment: It might sound silly, but is there anything blocking the lenses?

Comment: No error messages. When we try to calibrate, it just sits there doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Try contacting Xbox support (@XboxSupport on Twitter, probably other ways to contact them too). They might have some ideas to try to diagnose the problem.